# Module parse failed, webstorm, Ionic app

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript

I'm developing an hybrid app with Ionic, Cordova, Angular with the IDE WebStorm and I get this error. I don't know how I could fix it.

```
 SCRIPT5022: SCRIPT5022: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (48:0)
 You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| @Component({

|   selector: 'page-pieces',template:/*ion-inline-start:"C:\Users\oueslati 
 sirine\test\src\pages\pieces\pieces.html"*/'!-- -->\nion-header>\n  ion- 
 navbar color="primary">\n    ion-title>\n      span ion-text>Pieces/span>\n    
 /ion-title>\n  /ion-navbar>\n\n  !--  -->\n  ion-toolbar padding 
 color="light">\n    p ion-text no-margin class="text-white">\n      
 strong>4/strong> results found!\n    /p>\n  /ion-toolbar>\n\n/ion- 
 header>\n\nion-content padding class="trips detail-bg">\n  !--list of trips- 
 ->\n  !--div class="trip card" *ngFor="let p of info" margin-bottom>\n    
 div class="background border-bottom">\n      div class="background-filter 
 rlt"  >\n        div class="align-bottom" padding-left padding-right>\n          
 h6 class="pull-left text-white" ion-text> Nom :{{p.nom }}/h6>\n          h6 
 class="pull-right text-white" ion-text>{{p.robot }}/h6>\n          h
 main.js (91,1)
```

Comment: are you using angular or angularjs? by the error code it looks like youre using angular

Comment: and im pretty sure that `'!-- -->` needs to be `'<!-- -->`

Comment: i think angular , i use typescript